# calling a function in view controller of Utility app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I am new to objective C and I have a c++ background. I want to display a value in the label on the screen. I am calling the label value from the MainView.m. However, the label becomes blank after I click a button instead of printing a value. What is the problem? Here is the code.

**MainView.h**

@interface MainView : UIView {
 int a;
}

-(int) vr;

@end

**MainView.m**

-(int) vr
{
 return 100;
}

@end

**MainViewController.h**

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController  {

IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

NSMutableString  *displayString;

MainView *view1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *displayString;

- (IBAction)showInfo;
- (IBAction) pressButton:(id) sender;

@end

**MainViewController.m**

@synthesize myLabel, displayString;

-(IBAction) pressButton:(id) sender{

```
[displayString appendFormat:@"%i", view1.vr];
myLabel.text = displayString;}



 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 view1 = [[MainView alloc] init];
 [super viewDidLoad];}

- (void)dealloc {
[view1 dealloc];
[super dealloc];}
```

I have not mentioned code that had been auto generated. This is enough to get the whole picture. I tried a lot to debug this thing. I believe that IBAction carries out direct command such that

> myLabel.text = @"string";

but it does not invoke any method or class. Any subtle ideas? Thanks.

Comment: what happens if u add in other text in the stringWithFormat..does that get shown? if it does, its a problem with initializing view1, if not it is a problem with initializing the displayString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few issues:

**1**
In `MainView.h` you declare `-(id) vr;`
And in `MainView.m` it returns int.

**2**
Maybe `pressButton` is not connected to the right event in Interface Builder (it is usually touch up inside).
Try to write to log in this method.

**3**
Maybe `myLabel` is not connected to the label in the Interface Builder.
Try to set tome hard-coded string to label's text property.

**4**
Do you initiate `view1` in some place?
Can you post this piece of code too?

**5**
You can use `[displayString appendFormat:@"%i", view1.vr];`...

**EDIT** (due to changes in question):

**6**
The line `[super viewDidLoad];` should be the first line inside `viewDidLoad`.

**7**
`[view1 dealloc];` - never call `dealloc` directly on objects. Call `release` instead. The only place, where you can and should use `dealloc` is the line `[super dealloc];` inside `dealloc` method.

**8**
When you format your question/answer in Stack Overflow, remember that each code line should start with at least 4 spaces (or tab). Try reformatting you question by adding 4 spaces in the beginning of each code line.

**9**
I think that `displayString` is not initiated. Add the next line in the `viewDidLoad`: `displayString = [NSMutableString new];`

Comment: 1) The mistake has been corrected.
2) The pressButton is connected to the touch inside.
3) The label is connected with the proper field. It works with the myLabel.text = @"string";
4) and 5) The updated code is posted. 

After some analysis, I have found that, pressing the button carries out the command directly coded in the IBAction (See #3). However, IBAction does not invoke any method or class.

Comment: The real problem was the string displayString was not initiated. I added displayString = [NSMutableString new]; and it worked. Thanks for your help.